# Which Dijon station does the Milan-Paris Thello train stop at?

Tags: trains, france, transportation

The Thello train running from Milan to Paris stops in Dijon. However, neither Seat61 nor Thello's own website indicate which Dijon station it stops at. According to DB's website, there is Dijon Ville and Dijon Porte Nueve. According to Google Maps, these are not one in the same. Assuming I'm not researching this incorrectly (apologies if I am), which Dijon stop does the Milan-to-Paris Thello train stop at?

NB: I'm trying to transfer from Dijon to Basel SBB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Look it up on the DB website](http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/traininfo.exe/en/587193/421879/244816/73323/80) (I don't know if this link is permanent — just search for trains from Milano to Dijon). The train stops at Dijon-Ville. In fact only regional trains stop at Dijon-Porte-Neuve, only Dijon-Ville is on the line from Paris to Lyon, Switzerland and the Alps.

Going from Milan to Basel via Dijon is rather roundabout. Unless you get a really good deal and want to save on a hotel night, I recommend taking an evening or morning train (or even stopping on the way). If you leave Milano at 19:25, you can be in Basel around midnight. If you need to leave later, you can take the last train to [Bellinzona](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Bellinzona) (but since it's a small town, check if there's a hotel where you can arrive at 1am) and from there get to Basel in the morning.

Comment: (DB website link works for me, FYI)

Answer (score 3):

**Source 1  - Grounded Travel**

According to [GroundedTravel](http://www.groundedtravel.com/routes/rail/europe/paris-milan-venice-thello-sleeper-train):

> There is one service per day in either direction between Paris and
>   Venice. Daytime routes are also available via Milan.

and on their [Dijon page](http://www.groundedtravel.com/destinations/europe/france/dijon):

> The city's main station is **Gare de Dijon-Ville**, which provides
>   connections to Paris, Switzerland and beyond.

**Source 2 - Loco2**

Loco2 [states clearly that](https://loco2.com/blog/2013/01/thello-night-train-from-paris-to-florence-or-rome/) it's Dijon Ville.